# Can't get lastfm API to work correctly in Flash-Builder

Tags: api, flash-builder, last.fm

i have been trying to get the lastfm api working in flash builder.
Just as a test, i have been trying to receive profile images from the hyped bands.

I can send the request, but i have a problem with getting the right urls back.

For now i just stated a static url to see if that worked, and it does (see full code in the download link):

```
var api_selectedPhoto:String = "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/70775172.jpg";

            return api_selectedPhoto;
```

Anyway, my current XMLListCollection is myRequest.lastResult.artists.artist, which i refined from the debugger: Is it correct to not use the lfm tag, btw?

(i'm farily new here and not allowed to use images yet, so i'll just post the links the images)
http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/2497/api3.png

And this is how i try to add the url of the profile pics in the images inside a repeater:

```
<mx:Repeater id="lastfmCollection" dataProvider="{myRequest.lastResult.artists.artist}">
            <s:Label text="{haalChart(lastfmCollection.currentItem)}"/>
            <s:Image id="fotoKlein"
                     source="{haalChart(lastfmCollection.currentItem)}" 
                     width="80" height="80"
                     scaleMode="stretch"/>
        </mx:Repeater>
```

Point is also that there are 5 images--tags, each with a different "size" parameter from small to mega, inside the xml:

```
<image size="small">
    imageurlhere
</image>

<image size="medium">
    http...
</image>
```

Now,I need to know how I can get the medium sized images into my repeater. I have tried for days, but I'm stuck.

Here is the full code:

http://shortText.com/b0HlGpu

Any help is greatly appreciated!